# Automation tool or recorder for copy and paste contents

Tags: excel, automation, recorder

Few years back I saw a tool in office which was something like a recorder. An employee was copy and paste some data from different excel files in some manner and same activity was detected by that recorder tool. After that when he ran that tools all contents was filled automatically in few seconds. I am looking for same kind of tool now. Can anyone tell me what is this tool. It was different from macro and can be used in between different files.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at - https://www.mjtnet.com/index.htm - it sounds a bit like what you are describing.